# regression by group

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

Just a very quick question,  I want to run the regression using MASS. The dependent variable are val1, val2, val3 respectively and independent variables are a, b, c, d.

Just look at the fake data.

```
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
test <- data.table(val1 = 1:10, val2 = 11:20, val3 = 21:30, a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), d = rnorm(10))
summary1 <- glm.nb(val1 ~ a + b + c + d, data = test)
summary2 <- glm.nb(val2 ~ a + b + c + d, data = test)
summary3 <- glm.nb(val3 ~ a + b + c + d, data = test)
```

I think the code is ugly. I tried this

```
for (i in c("val1", "val2", "val3")){
paste("sum_", c("val1", "val2", "val3"), sep = "") <- glm.nb(i ~ a + b + c + d, data = simple)
}
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestions about the improvements?
In the original data, there're about 26 independent variables, and I think it will be more ugly if the code is like this `sum1 <- glm.nb(val3 ~ a + b + c + d + e + f+ g + h + i + j + k + l, data = test)`

I know the following code might be helpful, but I don't know how to use them...:(

```
diff <- setdiff(colnames(test),c('val1','val2','val3'))
```

Also, I wonder whether lapply function can achieve this within data.table?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you are creating the object name with `paste`, you need to use `assign(.)` instead of `<-`

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this within data.table. Just use something like `lapply(c("val1", "val2", "val3"), function(i, dat) glm.nb(paste0(i, " ~ a + b + c + d"), data = dat), dat=test)`.

Comment: ideally something like this would work, but not yet ([FR added](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5285&group_id=240&atid=978)): `test[, lapply(.SD, function(i) glm.nb(i ~ a + b + c + d)), .SDcols = grep('val', names(test))]`

Comment: don't forget `reformulate(".",response=response_name)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to put your data in the long format :

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
xx <- melt(test,measure.vars=paste0('val',1:3))
ddply(xx,.(variable),function(x){
  coef(glm.nb(value~.,data=subset(x,select=-variable)))
})

 variable (Intercept)            a            b           c          d
1     val1    1.583602 -0.045909060 -0.018189342 0.026293033 0.29708648
2     val2    2.704601 -0.014641683 -0.003836401 0.006711503 0.10445377
3     val3    3.217729 -0.008925782 -0.001863267 0.003475509 0.06292286
```

If you want all the model  not just the coefficients:

```
dlply(xx,.(variable),function(x){
  glm.nb(value~.,data=subset(x,select=-variable))
})
```

Comment: +1, I independently came up with the `data.table` version of this, but it's pretty much identical.

Comment: Why not post the data.table equivalent? I'd vote for it.

Comment: @BrodieG The data.table equiavalent need the  new `melt` function which is (as far as I know) still under development.

Comment: Yes, though in my unposted answer I ran the melt on the data frame version before converting to `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

Using your loop approach I would simply store all my models in a list like so

```
results <- list()

for (i in c("val1", "val2", "val3")){
  frml <- paste(i, "~ a + b + c + d")
  frml <- as.formula(frml)

  results[[i]] <- glm.nb(frml, data = simple)
}
```

And then access the models in the list by looking at `results$val1` etc.

Comment: Well, then you should use `lapply`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But only if the user knows what `lapply` is and is comfortable writing functions.

Comment: They shouldn't use data.table if they aren't. ;)

Comment: ^^^   well that was just too funny  (I'll be deleting this momentarily)

Comment: If you're going to use loops then you should pre-allocate objects instead of growing them each iteration...

Comment: If we're worried about allocation we probably should just use `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

And here is a solution with `lapply`:

```
summary.list<-lapply(test[, .SD, .SDcols=patterns('val')],
                     function(i) glm.nb(i ~ a + b + c + d, data = test))
```

Comment: Actually, I think you need `paste`.